# could not compile linux 2.6.19

Tags: linux-kernel

When i am trying to compile linux kernel 2.6.19 in my x86_64 machine the following error occurs, How to handle this error.

```
scripts/mod/sumversion.c: In function 'get_src_version':
scripts/mod/sumversion.c:384:16: error: 'PATH_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
char filelist[PATH_MAX + 1];
            ^
scripts/mod/sumversion.c:384:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/mod/sumversion.c:384:7: warning: unused variable 'filelist' [-Wunused-variable]
char filelist[PATH_MAX + 1];
   ^
scripts/Makefile.host:134: recipe for target 'scripts/mod/sumversion.o' failed
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/sumversion.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:324: recipe for target 'scripts/mod' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
Makefile:432: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, this is a result of known [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17561), which targets exactly version you use (and some others):

> To summarize, I have this problem with 2.6.17, 2.6.18.8, 2.6.19.7, 2.6.20.21.

Try others versions or apply patch suggestes in given bugreport:

```
diff -r 557a4a0a5eac scripts/mod/sumversion.c
--- a/scripts/mod/sumversion.c  Fri May 30 19:08:50 2008 +0100
+++ b/scripts/mod/sumversion.c  Mon Jun 02 19:47:43 2008 +0900
@@ -8,6 +8,7 @@
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include "modpost.h"
+#include <linux/limits.h>

 /*
  * Stolen form Cryptographic API.
```